# How to include abraham/twitteroauth library in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter

i'm trying to include [abraham/twitteroauth library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) on word press as default way not using composer i manage to include Facebook `SDK` like this

```
$dirName = dirname(__FILE__);
require_once ("$dirName/php/facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0-dev/src/Facebook/autoload.php");
```

in the `function.php` file and with the abraham/twitteroauth library i did the same thing but it give me an error when using it

```
require_once ("$dirName/php/twitteroauth/autoload.php"); 

function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
    return $connection;
}

    $connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

    $tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

    echo json_encode($tweets);
```

the error is

```
Fatal error: Class 'TwitterOAuth' not found in C:\wamp\www\website\wp-content\themes\twentythirteen\users.php on line 22
```

please any help and many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i used this [library](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php) instead and it work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include the right path to the library, and for the `use` statement to work this piece of code must be at the global level of a PHP file - not inside a function.

```
session_start();
require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '../lib/twitteroauth/autoload.php');
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
```

Then you can use the library like so:

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($twitter_consumer_key, $twitter_consumer_secret, $twitter_oauth_access_token, $twitter_oauth_access_token_secret);
$response = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");
```

See [TwitterOAuth](https://twitteroauth.com/) for more info.